# How to split string with unequal amount of spaces

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am currently struggling, with splitting a string with a varying amount of spaces, coming from a log file.

**An excerpt of the log file:**

```
ProcessA   Mon Nov  9 09:59 - 10:48  (00:48)            
ProcessB     Sun Nov  8 11:16 - 11:17  (00:00)          
ProcessC  Sat Nov  7 12:52 - 12:53  (00:00)             
ProcessD   Fri Nov  6 09:31 - 11:25  (01:54)            
ProcessE  Thu Nov  5 16:41 - 16:41  (00:00)             
ProcessF  Thu Nov  5 11:39 - 11:40  (00:00)
```

As you can see the amount of spaces between the process name and the date of execution varies between 2 to 5 spaces.
I would like to split it up into three parts; - process, date of execution, and execution time.

However I don’t see a solution to that, because of the unequal amount of spaces. Am I wrong or is splitting such a string incredibly hard?

Hopefully somebody out there is way smarter than me and can provide me with a solution for that

Thanks to everybody in advance, who is willing trying to help me with that!

Comment: What's wrong with `while IFS=' ' read -r process_name executation_date; do printf '%s %s\n' "$process_name" "$executation_date"; done <file.log`?

Comment: `awk '$1=$1' file.txt` can remove extra spaces.

Answer (score 4):

You can also assign fields directly in a `read`.

```
while read -r prc wd mon md start _ end dur _; do
  echo "prc='$prc' wd='$wd' mon='$mon' md='$md' start='$start' end='$end' dur='${dur//[)(]/}'"
done < file
```

Output:

```
prc='ProcessA' wd='Mon' mon='Nov' md='9' start='09:59' end='10:48' dur='00:48'
prc='ProcessB' wd='Sun' mon='Nov' md='8' start='11:16' end='11:17' dur='00:00'
prc='ProcessC' wd='Sat' mon='Nov' md='7' start='12:52' end='12:53' dur='00:00'
prc='ProcessD' wd='Fri' mon='Nov' md='6' start='09:31' end='11:25' dur='01:54'
prc='ProcessE' wd='Thu' mon='Nov' md='5' start='16:41' end='16:41' dur='00:00'
prc='ProcessF' wd='Thu' mon='Nov' md='5' start='11:39' end='11:40' dur='00:00'
```

`read` generally doesn't care how much whitespace is between.

Comment: read doesn't care ... only if the default IFS (space, tab, newline) is in place. If IFS has some custom value, then read no longer respects *sequences* of IFS characters.

Comment: Entirely true. This is the default case. It still works if you explicitly set `IFS=' '` before the read, but unless you're changed it that shouldn't be necessary,.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, you can use a regex to parse each line:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
while IFS=' ' read -r line ; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ ([^\ ]+)\ +(.+[^\ ])\ +'('([^\)]+)')' ]] ; then
        process=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        date=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        time=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
        echo "$process $date $time."
    fi
done
```

Or, use parameter expansions:

```
#! /bin/bash
while IFS=' ' read -r process datetime ; do
    shopt -s extglob
    date=${datetime%%+( )\(*}
    time=${datetime#*\(}
    time=${time%\)}
    echo "$process $date $time."
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{printf $1; for (i=2; i<NF; i++) printf " %s",$i; print "",$NF}' < file.txt
```

produces:

```
ProcessA Mon Nov 9 09:59 - 10:48 (00:48)
ProcessB Sun Nov 8 11:16 - 11:17 (00:00)
ProcessC Sat Nov 7 12:52 - 12:53 (00:00)
ProcessD Fri Nov 6 09:31 - 11:25 (01:54)
ProcessE Thu Nov 5 16:41 - 16:41 (00:00)
ProcessF Thu Nov 5 11:39 - 11:40 (00:00)
```

Comment: Always use a format string wth printf: `printf "%s", $1` -- that guards against a string containing the `%` character.

Comment: `awk '$1=$1' file.txt` much simpler ;)

Comment: @BarathVutukuri  question: "... I would like to split it up into three parts; - process, date of execution, and execution time."

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano the above command produces the same output as yours. I understand that the question has asked for 3 parts from the text. Just posting an alternate to yours 